# Set OpenFeint Custom Start Tab (iPhone App)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openfeint

I'm currently setting up OpenFeint for an iPhone application. By default, the first tab that loads is "Friends" (the third tab in the tab view list) but I'd like to customize this to load the main tab for our application (the first tab in the list).

Anyone know how to accomplish this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following all the startup logic I finally found this function in OpenFeint+Private.mm:

```
+ (void)presentRootControllerWithTabbedDashboard
{
    UITabBarController* tabController = (UITabBarController*)OFControllerLoader::load(@"TabbedDashboard");
    if (![OpenFeint lastLoggedInUserHadFriendsOnBootup])
    {
        tabController.selectedIndex = 2;
    }
    [OpenFeint presentRootControllerWithModal:tabController];
}
```

As expected, changing .selectedIndex to 0 works perfect.